# "Controller as" not updating binding

Tags: angularjs

I honestly have no idea why this does not work. It should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/4utpnsh9/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="IndexController as vm">
    <span>{{vm.Timer}}</span>
</div>
```

Angular

```
$interval(function() {
    this.Timer = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0);
}, 1000);
```

When `this.Timer` updates, it does not update in the view. It does when I `console.log()` it though. If I remove the `vm.Timer` and simply makes it `Timer` and apply it to `$scope` instead of `this`, it works flawlessly, as you can see for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/4utpnsh9/1/

I've done this multiple times on another stack than this one, but for some reason I can't figure out why it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `this` isn't what you think it is! `this` is changing contexts in the callback of the interval. Either use arrow functions, or set some context!

```
$interval(() => {
    this.Timer = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0);
}, 1000);
```

Or

```
$interval(function() {
    this.Timer = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0);
}.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: Aaahhh dammit! I'm used to Typescript, so when I go back to the ancient stuff, I forget all the shizz! Thanks a lot, dude haha.

Comment: @MortenMoulder -- Going back to regular JS after TypeScript is like moving back into your college dorm after owning a house :) - always happy to help